# C++0x: applying function over multiple iterators

Tags: templates, c++11, variadic-functions, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a function that would map a function over multiple iterators. It would be something like

```
template <class Fun>
fun_over_variadic_args(Fun fun) { }

template <class Fun, class First, class Rest...> 
fun_over_variadic_args(Fun fun, First& first, Rest&... rest) { 
  fun(first); 
  fun_over_variadic_args(fun, rest...);
}

namespace { 
  template <class T> struct thunk_inc { 
    decltype(T::operator++()) operator()(T& t) { return ++t; } 
  }; 
}

template <class Fun, class MainIterator, class RestOfIterators...>
std::tuple<MainIt&, RestOfIts&...> map_over_iterators(Fun fun, MainIt& it, MainIt& end, RestOfIts&... rest) {
const thunk_inc();
for (; it!=end; fun_over_variadic_args(thunk_inc, it, rest...)) {
      // Do something
    }
}
```

The problem arises then that the function Fun in fun_over_variadic_args needs to be templated which means it cannot be a lambda and cannot be a local function object which entails polluting the global namespace.

Does someone know a better solution to this? 
Thanks

Edit: Note that I want the maximum speed possible so solutions that preserve the possibility of inlining all the function calls would be preferred.

Edit2: Just realized that I could use anonymous namespaces to limit the scope of function Fun to one file. I would still love to know a neater solution though if one exists.

*Alternate solution* I found that I can apply a function fun to a variadic argument pack as long as I pass the result to another function. So if I have a function fun which I want to apply to every argument, I can do something like

```
template <class... T>
void foo(T... t) { }

template <class... Arg>
void test(Arg... arg) {
  foo(fun(arg)...); // Works!
  fun(arg)...; // Doesn't work! 
}
```

*Clarification for alternate solution* Using this however means that fun cannot return void

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would use this, or even better say what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: The specific solution for fun_over_variadic_args would be used in map_over_iterators. In general, it could have a use anywhere where one needs to apply a function to multiple values which are specified as variadic arguments.

Comment: @Sid: Would you mind making up a minimal example that would show the actual use of this object?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Wrote the code for map_over_iterators that demonstrates the usage of fun_over_variadic_args

Comment: @Sid: Hm, I don't understand, how are the end iterators supposed to be passed? Are all the ranges required to be equal? Do you want them to be processed in parallel, or one range after the other? What's wrong with just using `for_each` on each range?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: All the ranges are required to be equal. I'm not sure if for_each can handle multiple cases at once. The use case I'm envisioning is what if I want elements at position x from all the ranges where position x is determined by a query on each element of the main iterator's range.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Another use case for fun_over_variadic_args might be if I wanted to write say a sort function that sorts all the ranges according to the first range

Comment: Note that this could be achieved trivially in C++03 with [`boost::zip_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) + [`boost::fusion::fused`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/functional/adapters/fused.html).

Comment: @Sid: Wait, do you just want to sort a couple of containers according to one key container? In that case you could just make a big vector of tuples and write a comparison functor that compares by first member and use the standard sort algorithm...

Comment: @ildjarn: Good idea! Now I understand what the OP intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, given your additional description of the problem, perhaps something variadic like this will do:

```
template <typename ItHead, typename... ItTail>
void advance_iterators(ItHead & it, ItTail ...others)
{
  ++it;
  advance_iterators(others...);
}

template <typename It>
void advance_iterators(ItHead & it)
{
  ++it;
}

template <typename Fun, typename ItMain, typename ...ItOthers>
apply_helper(Fun & f, ItMain it, ItOthers ...others)
{
   f(*it);
   apply_helper(f, others...);
}

template <typename Fun, typename ItMain, typename ...ItOthers>
apply_helper(Fun & f, ItMain it)
{
   f(*it);
}

template <typename Fun, typename ItMain, typename ...ItOthers>
apply (Fun & f, ItMain begin, ItMain end, ItOthers ...others)
{
  while (begin != end)
  {
    apply_helper(f, begin, others...);
    advance_iterators(begin, others...);
  }
}
```

The obvious restrictions here are that `Fun` has to work on all the value-types of the iterators, and that the ranges have to be equal. The function object is passed by reference, you can modify that to taste.

**Update:** If I misunderstood and you want `f` to operate on all values simultaneously, then you should get rid of `apply_helper` and just call `f(begin, others...)` and make a function `f` that takes all those iterators.